# How to use sonata_type_model_autocomplete in a custom template?

Tags: symfony, autocomplete, sonata-admin

i have tried to use **sonata_type_model_autocomplete** in a create custom template using :

```
$builder->add('user', 'sonata_type_model_autocomplete', array('property'=>'eMail'));
```

but it's not working , is there a different way to use it.